# Making image darker with background-color

Tags: css

I have an image that I want to make darker using an rgba background but I can't seem to get it to work. The color of the image doesn't change.

Here's what the html looks like:

```
<div class="image">

<div class="darker">
<img src="url">
</div>

</div>
```

and the css:

```
.image {
 width: 100%
 height: 100px;
 position: relative;

 }

.darker {
 background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.5);      

 }
```

Comment: That's probably because the image itself is not transparent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your HTML code to this:

```
<div class="image">
    <img src="..." />
    <div class="darker"></div>
</div>
```

And use CSS to position the .darker div over the image. Then you can use opacity to "make it darker":

```
.image { position: relative; }
.darker { position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; background-color: #000; opacity: 0.5; width: 100%; height: 100% }
```